# calling c function from nasm x86-64

Tags: c, x86-64, nasm

Working on calling a C function from my asm project.

I'm trying to push the integer value into the c function.

My code

```
mov rdi, [input]
push rdi                  ;push rdi into stack for c function to work with
call dtoch
pop  rdi                  ;to keep stack balanced
```

'
am I moving the input into the wrong register ?

Running on linux Ubuntu OS, not getting an error, it's just not printing out the correct value.

When I run the function in a C environement it works fine,  but with my nasm project it prints out wrong numbers....?

c function:

```
void dtoch(int d )
{
int n , r[10], i = 0, number, j = 0;
while (number > 0)
{
r[i] = number%16;
number = number/16;
i++;
j++;
}
printf ("It's hexadecimal equivalent is: ");
for (i = j -1; i > = 0; i--)
{
if (r[i] == 10)
printf("A");
else if (r[i] == 11)
printf("B");
else if (r[i] == 12)
printf("C");
else if (r[i] == 13)
printf("D");
else if (r[i] == 14)
printf("E");
else if (r[i] == 15)
printf("F");
else
printf("%d", r[i]);
}

}
```

Comment: The called function doesn't care what register you use to push the argument onto the stack. What is the calling convention of the C func? Are you getting an error? You need to give more information.

Comment: Show the C function prototype.

Comment: Write a C function that calls the other C function and look at the assembly listing to see how it is done.

Comment: are you missing a number = d in your C code?  I don't see where you use the passed in argument.  Also, you are missing your stack-alignment.  amd64 calling convention says the stack must be 16-byte aligned when you issue the call.

Comment: jcopenha             I am missing the assignment to numer, but when I try to assign it, I  get an error "d" redeclared as different kind of symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x64 uses `__fastcall` *only*, for Linux, the AMD64 ABI is used, see Agner fog's [optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) for the differences or this nice summery table [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI_convention) (on windows, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx) (Microsoft ABI)).

For your example running under Linux , you want it in `RDI`, **no `PUSH`s(and the paired `POP`'s) are needed**. You can review the full AMD64 ABI [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.pdf), it includes a few coding smaples (on windows you'd want your single arg to go into `RCX`, again, no `PUSH`'s needed.).

A a simple tip: you can compile your c calls with assembly output and see what code the compiler generates, the options `-Wa,-adhln -g` on GCC should do the trick.

Comment: I tried to remove the push's and pops, I also assigned the number being brought into the function to "number" variable, but its only giving me a generic number of 2 in every run....

Comment: Terminology nitpick: The x86-64 System V ABI's calling convention is *not* called `__fastcall`.  It uses different register than the MS Windows x64 non-vectorcall calling convention ([which MS calls x64 __fastcall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019)), and has a red-zone but not shadow space.  It doesn't really have a name AFAIK; I call it the x86-64 System V calling convention, or SysV for short.  (Like GCC's `__attribute__((sysv_abi))`.)